# Why iOS Safari loads JS file after </html> tag after 30 seconds of HTML loading

Tags: javascript, html

To share an interesting observation of <script> tag after </html>. 
We have a HTML page which is written in below way:

```html
<html>
    <body>...</body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ....
    </script>
```

The page is embedded into an iOS app, and we found randomly the page is loaded more than 30seconds. 
After diagnostics using Safari Web Inspection feature to record timeline, we found the way of writing the <script> tag after </html> causing mobile Safari or iOS UIWebView to start loading util.js after 30seconds of finishing loading the containing HTML page.

Is there a specific reason of this 30 seconds waiting before loading the util.js?

Comment: `<script>` cannot be self-closed, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"/>` will not load the file

Comment: That js file might be taking the time to load??

Comment: @Tushar, updated the code sample. The production code doesn't have self-closed <script> tag.

Comment: @AkshayJ, the file is very small, less than 5kB. It should be loaded instantly.

Comment: Why is your HTML written in this way? It is invalid.

Comment: @Lee, I understand this is absolutely invalid, just curious about why this is so slow to load.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any tags outside of the  tags, it is pure malformed html syntax.

Comment: I understand this is invalid, just curious about why this leads to that long latency to load, ;-)